# classes design in OOA

Tags: oop, design-patterns, object-oriented-analysis

We want to apply OO to design a process of taking an exam and getting the result.
There are two different opinions:

1. there are 2 objects: questionnaire and algorithm. questionnaire is storing questions and the final result, and the algorithm is for calculating to get the result;
2. there are 3 objects: questionnaire, algorithm and result, and here, the result is seperated to be one object which is just for storing the result.

My question is which one is a better OO design? Or, what is a correct OO design in this case?

If I want to record a user's answers, is it need to create an object as "Answers" which is connected with questionnare and algorithm?

Comment: you may want to check out Analysis Patterns: Reusable Object Models http://www.amazon.com/Analysis-Patterns-Reusable-Object-Models/dp/0201895420

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 2nd design is better than 1st.

If later you want to generate report, just collect all `Result` objects and prepare it.

and, Each question will have an `Answer` object attached to it. so `Questionnaire` will contain a list of `Question` and `Answer` objects.

For example: `Questionnaire` object may contain following attributes:

1. Id or RollNo.
2. Name.
3. Date.
4. Subject.
5. List of questions
6. List of answers.

5 & 6 can be combined to list of `Question` object. and this object may be composed of an `Answer` object. So, only List of questions will suffice.

> If I want to record a user's answers, is it need to create an object as "Answers" which is connected with questionnare and algorithm?

No, `Algorithm` need not be connected (such as composition) to `Answer`. It should take `Question` and `Answer` as input and return `Result`.

> My question is which one is a better OO design? Or, what is a correct OO design in this case?

Find out the different users for our system, their expectations, explicit & implicit requirements, Input format, Output format, and you'll *discover* ur design.

For example:

How a user will provide answer? is it simple text, subjective, objective, how many options? etc...

Comment: Should the Questionnaire Object hav a reference of the Result Object
？

Comment: Yes, it should. How will you identify that which `Questionaire` matches to which `Result`. OR you can simply have common id in both objects. but i'll prefer former.

Comment: questionnaire algorithm and result class are abstract classes, i just need to pass the correct type of algorithm to result, I can get the certain result,isnt it?

Comment: Oh, yes. This way is also looks good. based on different `Algorithm` passed, a different `Result` will be prepared. But ideally it should not be job of `Result` to prepare itself.